# Why do CSS transitions occur for unshift() and not for shift() in ng-repeat lists?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, css-transitions

I'm moving some elements in the page using `ng-repeat` and CSS transitions. If I change the data array using `unshift` the list transitions nicely. (In my application I'm transitioning position as well as opacity.)

If, however, I use `shift` to update the array, the DOM is updated immediately with no transition.

**[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/w123q5na/)** of one approach, where all works as expected aside from the transitions. Compare the behavior when using the two buttons.

```
$scope.items.push( $scope.items.shift() );
```

**[Here's another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/urr79ox0/)** of an alternative approach, where the transitions work, but the array loses an element each time the function runs.

```
$scope.items.shift( $scope.items.push() );
```

The idea is that the user can cycle through the items in the array indefinitely and the CSS transitions occur in both directions. What seems to be the issue is that AngularJS updates the DOM in one case, but not in the other, though I wasn't able to demonstrate that in my testing.

Also, based on some reading I did I tried using `track by item.id` with no success. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very curious.

I was playing around with different possible solutions and one thing I found is that if you change your slide up to:

```
$scope.slideUp = function() {
    $scope.items.push( angular.copy($scope.items.shift()) );
};
```

It will animate the third item. So it could be a reference issue within angular?

Note: In my fiddle below, while playing around I also made changes to your `ng-class` and css, but it still works the same with your first demo fiddle.

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ysyh699u/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Indeed that does seem to work. Here's a fiddle demonstrating something more like what I'm actually doing. I'm having trouble getting it to work in my app, though. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/w123q5na/5

Comment: Bingo. I had a `track by` statement left in my template that was bunging things up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it instead of creating a new object every time is to trick Angular's ng-repeat into thinking it's a new object.

```
$scope.inc = 9;

$scope.slideUp = function() {
    var item = $scope.items.shift();
    item.id = $scope.inc++;
    $scope.items.push( item );
};

$scope.slideDown = function() {
    var item = $scope.items.pop();
    item.id = $scope.inc++;
    $scope.items.unshift( item );
};
```

I added an id property to each object that I increment when sliding up or down, then set the ng-repeat to track by the id:

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w123q5na/3/)</kbd>

Comment: This seems to work, but it requires changing the data model, no?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem.

In your first "faulty" demo, you can see that when you press "Slide up", `Item One` will indeed fade out, but it appears on the bottom of the page! That's because you add it as the last element, and only then it begins its transition.

On `Sliding down`, the element is just pushed down and hence you see the transition more intuitively, namely coupled close with the first three elements, but actually the same thing happens.

What still puzzles me is why Asok's solution works the way you would expect it. I'll edit when I think of a reason.